# Dynamic query using bigquery and data studio

Tags: google-bigquery, dynamic-sql, looker-studio

I want to take out data for every date range in Data Studio without the need to change date range selectors in my BigQuery all the time. However, not sure if it is even possible to do so. The reasons I do this is to make sure that the queried data is only for 30 days, as later it do some kind of segmentation using that 30 days data.

Then I figured out that the Data Studio can use dynamic_date, however this way will never produce any datatable (datatable will be used to do other queries from it). Is it possible to do dynamic_date in BigQuery instead? like retrieving data from BigQuery using a date range not previously defined in the query.

From my point of view, code should be like :

```
SELECT
   ID, 
   FROM `table`
   WHERE DATE(Timestamp) between $DS_START_DATE and  $DS_START_DATE + INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

or

```
WHERE DATE(Timestamp) >= @DS_START_DATE
```

Comment: Are you looking for Bigquery [parameterized](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) queries? However, currently they are not supported in classic BigQuery web UI.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in pure Bigquery you can use `DECLARE` [clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare) for that purpose, defining variables of the specified type:

```
declare DS_START_DATE date default "2020-03-03";
declare DS_END_DATE date default "2020-03-04";

WITH sample AS (
  SELECT '10001' AS id,  cast('2020-03-01' AS timestamp) as date_id UNION ALL
  SELECT '10002', cast('2020-03-02' AS timestamp) UNION ALL
  SELECT '10003', cast('2020-03-03' AS timestamp) UNION ALL
  SELECT '10004', cast('2020-03-04' AS timestamp) UNION ALL
  SELECT '10005', cast('2020-03-05' AS timestamp) UNION ALL
  SELECT '10006', cast('2020-03-06' AS timestamp)
)
select id, date_id from sample

where date(date_id) between DS_START_DATE and DS_END_DATE
```

Alternatively, you can take a look at [parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries), however as I mentioned in the comment, they are not supported in classic BigQuery web UI.

Comment: yea. currently they are not supported.